# Run multiple Node js apps on single EC2 instance on different port

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2

Here is my node file

I have HTML on `/`

and node app on `/app`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxx/fullchain.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxxx/privkey.pem";
    # It is *strongly* recommended to generate unique DH parameters
    # Generate them with: openssl dhparam -out /etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem 2048
    #ssl_dhparam "/etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:SEED:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!RSAPSK:!aD$
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


        location / {
        # This would be the directory where your frontend code resides
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;
    return 302 https://xxxxx.com;
}
```

I have also forwarded 3000 port to 80;

I want to run multiple apps on this server on a different port.

What config should I have for other apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is Nginx config file.

The question is what exactly You want to achieve.

1. Scenario: **Different domains**
   Add more config files to NGINX with different `server_name app1.com`, `server_name app2.com` etc ...  Each config should forward to another Node app on different ports.
2. Scenario: **One domain and different PATH**. 
   Multiply location paragraph. Eg. to existing config file add new `location /app1`paragraph which forwards to Node App on a different port.

Comment: I have to also add A record to IP in my domain DNS for second scenario.

Comment: If scenario same ip but different ports. Is it possible?

Comment: yes, different ports are the easiest way to dispatch traffic. Just add `ports` to the configuration of containers.